# Run a command over directories with name recursively

Tags: bash, shell, files, recursive, chown

I have the following directory structure in AIX.

```
codeRepo/REPO1/AREA1/objects
codeRepo/REPO1/AREA2/SUBAREA1/objects
codeRepo/REPO1/AREA2/SUBAREA2/objects
```

From codeRepo I want to run `chown myUser *` on each `objects` directory in the tree. As you can see there are various objects directories sitting in different places.

Comment: do you need something more general-case than `chown myUser REPO1/AREA1/objects/* REPO1/AREA2/SUBAREA1/objects/* REPO1/AREA2/SUBAREA2/objects/*`? If you're OK with including every subdirectory, then something like `chown myUser */*/objects/* */*/*/objects/*` would catch "objects" directories at 2- and 3-layers deep.

Comment: Use `find(1)` to look for the files you are interested in, and use `-exec` to mangle their permissions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to chown the directories only (and not the subfiles), use `find -exec`, as like:

```
find -type d -name objects -exec chown myUser {} \;
```

Going through this:
`-type d` selects only directories
`-name objects` looks only for directories named exactly "objects"
`-exec chown myUser {} \;` executes `chown myUser {}` for each path found (with {} replaced by the path)

If you want to also `chown` all the files inside as well, just replace `chown` with `chown -R`.

Comment: This is the best answer I believe. I was particularly interetested in executing the command only on the objects directory.

Answer (score 1):

You almost answered your own question.. the answer is to use the recursive option -R

run the command **sudo chown -R richie codeRepo/** (assuming your username is richie)

This will recursively set each file/folder to you as the owner, but does so; as far down the tree as it can get so is more of a *sledgehammer* approach.

Answer (score 1):

Use `bash` option `globstar` to traverse through any depth by `**`.

While at `codeRepo`:

```
shopt -s globstar
chown myUser REPO1/AREA*/**/objects
```

For preciseness, if there is only one digit (character) after `AREA` in the name, use `?` to indicate a single character:

```
chown myUser REPO1/AREA?/**/objects
```

Likewise, for two characters:

```
chown myUser REPO1/AREA??/**/objects
```